# Не срабатывает CSS стиль для изображения в мобильной версии

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Вот это ЧБ изображение, на данной странице https://f8t.ru/trenirovki-rostov/ должно было растянуться в мобильной версии, но осталось уменьшенной как есть.

Код в css:

```
.single-featured-image-header img {

  height: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.single-featured-image-header {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Подскажите, почему не срабатывает CSS?

Answer (score 0):

responsive.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.single-featured-image-header img {width: 100%;margin-top: -20px;}
```